# Access 2007 Transform transactional table to summary

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have a transaction style table in Access 2007. For example

```
ID Start Date   End Date    Type        Sub Type
1  1/01/2012    15/02/2012  Supermarket Bread
1  16/02/2012   20/03/2012  Supermarket Milk 
1  21/03/2012   30/09/2012  Supermarket Cheese
1  1/11/2012    15/11/2013  Hardware    Nails
```

Want I need to do is transform this into this:

```
ID Start Date   End Date    Type        
1  1/01/2012    30/09/2012  Supermarket
1  1/11/2012    15/11/2013  Hardware
```

A single record per ID with the start date from the first 'supermarket' record through to the last 'supermarket' record.

Appreciate any suggestions/help with if this is possible in Access.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want an aggregate query which groups by `ID` and `Type`.  You can then use `Min()` and `Max()` to retrieve the earliest `Start Date` and the latest `End Date` within each group.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    [Type],
    Min([Start Date]) AS start_date,
    Max([End Date]) AS end_date
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY
    ID,
    [Type];
```